# Arduino mega - Serial connexion TX not working

Tags: arduino, serial-port

When i connect a serial module to my Arduino mega on pin number lowest of 50, i can't recive data but i can send data to RX. When i test on Arduino nano pro this work.

Used code :

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial Bt(49, 8);
String msg;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Bt.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

  while(Bt.available()) {
    delay(3);
    char c = Bt.read();
    msg += c;
  }


  while(Serial.available()) {
    delay(3);
    char c = Serial.read();
    Bt.print(c);
  }

  if(msg.length() > 0) {
    Serial.println(msg);
    msg = "";
  }

}
```

Comment: What for is delay in receiving? At 9600 3 bytes can pass in 3 ms.

Comment: Have you tested if the pin actually works?

Comment: I have removed delay but it still does not work and i have tested my pins, i t works corectly.